# Django URL Page error when link is clicked twice

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have a url defined as:

```
path("home/projects/",project_view,name = "viewProject")
```

This render correctly when i click on the 'Details' link on project_view.html

```
<li>
  <a href="projects" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tip-bottom" title="All Projects">
  <i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true">Details</i></a>
</li>
```

But while i am on the same page,if i click the same link again i get an error:

home/projects/ [name='viewProject']

"Page not found...The current path, **home/projects/projects**, didn't match any of these"

I understand what the error means,but how can i redirect the page to **"home/projects/"** if the link is clicked twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of writing the url patterens you should use the django url *[template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url)* like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'viewProject' %}" data-toggle="tooltip" class="tip-bottom" title="All Projects">
  <i class="fa fa-list" aria-hidden="true">Details</i></a>
```